# Using wp_localize_scripts

Tags: wp-localize-script

I'm trying to work out how to send a PHP variable from a page template to an AJAX function (which in turn pulls data via a function in functions.php using admin-ajax.php). I understand I'm meant to use wp_localize_script, but can't get it to work in either my page template or functions.php.

In functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_theme_scripts' );
function enqueue_theme_scripts() {  
    wp_register_script('xxx', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/xxx.js', array ( 'jquery' ), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('xxx');
    wp_localize_script( 'xxx', 'yyy', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'), 'a_value'=> '10' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'xxx', 'zzz', 'hello' );
}
```

So I'm trying to retrieve 'hello' as a variable in xxx.js. My understanding is that with the code above I should be able to do:

```
alert(zzz);
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

And how does it work if I want to grab a PHP variable from my page template php file, not from functions.php? I can't find any online examples...

Comment: are you expecting it in frontend or backend? did you try to view source code to see if `/assets/js/xxx.js` is loaded or not?

Comment: Front-end, and yep, xxx is loading fine.And if I do alert("hi"), it comes up. So it's literally just wp_localize_script that isn't working for me. (Although my wp_localize_script going to admin-ajax.php has always worked).

Comment: I think it is there. Only that `alert` not work, did you try to type `zzz` in inspector console to see if variable exists? If it exist, you `alert(zzz)` in console should work. I have tried your code, it works and it looks alright. If js file is loaded, when you view source and search `zzz` should be somewhere around. For the second question, what do you want to accomplish specifically. Would you mind giving examples?

Comment: It all magically works this morning. I'm mystified, as I spent hours last night trying to crack it. No problems whatsoever now :/

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest though! :)

Comment: Great that it resolve. I think one tips could help. Sometimes javascript might be cached, loading order is also affecting, sometimes browser cache. If you think the code is right, try more different browsers, incognito mode and so on will also help. Anyway, happy coding!